# How can I highlight element when mouse get over it

Tags: jquery, mozilla, highlighting

I want to highlight elements when I click on inspect button then click on specific elements, then the whole page will be grey and blocked and the selected element will be highlighted.

There's an amazing example on mozilla 6 plugin that inspect elements without using firebug, I wonder to be able to make like it or even use the plugin.

[image]

Also google plus send feedback use sth like this, can somebody  guide me how can I make it give me plugin that I can use..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think is possible to trigger something on inspect. This is browsers specific, plus not every browsers has inspect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711023/how-to-make-this-javascript-much-faster/4711224#4711224