# Get element currently under mouse without using mouse events

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mouseevent, xpcom

WRT building a Firefox Add-on.

Is it possible to get the element under the mouse via some XPCOM or javascript method? **(non-js-ctypes please as that requires OS specificity)**

I want to detect what is under the mouse when user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Right now I'm adding a `mouseover` listener to the document when the user presses this hotkey, so I can get the element under the mouse when he moves it, but not the element that was under the mouse exactly when he pressed the hotkey combination.

Comment: i would suggest having a listener on the `mousemove` event to track the mouse. then using the mouse's coordinates, find the element beneath it. this is annoying but possible. see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: The issue with `elementFromPoint` is I have to add `mousemove` and the element will not be available until user makes movement of mouse after pressing hotkey. I basically use the 2nd method in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4711224/3791822

Comment: listen on `mousemove` ALL the time, storing the position somewhere. then when the key combination is pressed, use the last recorded mouse position.

Comment: Oh yes that's an idea, I had that too but forgot to mention it so up vote for that. A persistent `mousemove` is not so good for performance especially from the add-on scope so I was hoping to avoid that please.

Comment: then you're probably out of luck. are you sure it hurts performance that much? i've done things like this before with little issue. a simple handler that updates xy values in an array is not very taxing. that's all it would need to do.

Comment: The add-on approval comitte warn against it. I can use it, but they prefer I find some alternative. They don't mind if I added the mousemove when the hotkey is pressed and remove it when user releases the hotkey, but elements in my add-on are zoomed real big, so pixel level, so a single pixel will select something else. :(

Comment: i can't think of another way to do this, then (at least using js)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just looked through the source for code that gets (or stores and makes available) the cursor position. I didn't find anything one could use (from Javascript, XPCOM or not). I might have missed something... [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/) is your friend.

However, if you want to avoid `mousemove` (and this is a good idea in general), you can just look for the innermost hovered element, e.g. like so.

```
function getInnermostHovered() {
    var n = document.querySelector(":hover");
    var nn;
    while (n) {
        nn = n;
        n = nn.querySelector(":hover");
    }
    return nn;
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vH54L/) demoing the principle)

While this is what I'd consider a hack, it seems to work good enough most of the time, but will fail if the element has mouse events disabled via [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events). There could be other issues I didn't think of...

Of course, this can return nothing when the document has no hovered element (e.g. the mouse is not actually within the document).

Comment: This is indeed a clever idea - I believe it can be simplified however using querySelectorAll as it's order should always be such that the element you want is at the end. i.e. `function getInnermostHovered() { return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(':hover')).pop(); }`

Comment: Interesting idea @SmokeyPHP

Comment: Indeed, `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(":hover")).pop()` would work, however for very large documents, depending on browser engine, I could imagine it will walk the entire tree looking for `:hover` while the recursive `.querySelector` would prune subtrees early on.  Or maybe browsers that matter have it optimized enough... Needs some performance testing.

Comment: Good point, it's brevity may not be worth the possible performance hit for certain document sizes/browsers. I've just run a few tests and it does indeed seem to be faster (in the latest FF & Chrome at least) to 'manually' walk the more specific tree - sometimes a negligible difference, but a difference nonetheless

Comment: For anyone looking now, MXR appears to have been replaced by [SearchFox](https://searchfox.org/).