# Find element under click causing blur

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-select

Is there any way to find out element the click causing blur even was made over?

I need to have value of a ui-select set to what user has typed in when he clicks outside of the dropdown. But when he clicks on the dropdown item the input should be discarded and item selected. So I should understand where was the mouse when user clicked outside ui-select's input. I tried

```
element.find('input').on('blur', function (e) {
       e.target  
  ...
 });
```

but target always points to the

input.form-control.ui-select-search.ng-valid.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse

The

[Get element currently under mouse without using mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538450/get-element-currently-under-mouse-without-using-mouse-events)

always finds highlighted dropdown item ad

[Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript)

doesn't work as I can't any of the DOM X/Y properties.

Any ideas?

ps: no jquery.

Comment: Please try to replicate the scenario using jsbin, jsfiddle...

Comment: You've tagged this with angularjs, it's perhaps worth looking at ng-blur? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: On `focus` of the input, set an `click` eventlistener on the root `document` element that first, identifies the element that received the click (the `event.target`, similar to your use above), then `for`/`while` loop through the `event.target` and all its parents (all the way up the DOM tree), looking for a match [of the "original" focused `<input>`]. If neither the `element.target` nor any of the parent/ancestors match, you found the element. Whether you return the match or not, you'll probably want to remove that eventListener when the handler is done.

Comment: Thank you  Ito Pizarro! That's probably the way to go - I was thinking about adding click (or maybe better mousedown) listener to the dropdown items (but they're added to dom dynamically) and forgotten that I can add it to parent elt and use event.target.

Comment: No problem! I really _should_ have submitted that as an answer so it's easier for anyone else to find. I'm fixing that now…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On focus of the input, set a `click` `eventListener` on the root document element that:

1. Identifies the element that received the click (the event.target, similar to your use above)
2. `for`/`while` loops through the `event.target` and all its parents (all the way up the DOM tree), looking for a match [of the "original" focused `<input>`]

If neither the `element.target` nor any of the parent/ancestors match, you found the element. Whether you return the match or not, you'll want to remove that `eventListener` when the handler is done.